# Trailing backslash of variable in ffmpeg command

Tags: ffmpeg, special-characters, drawtext

**Issue detail:**

I use ffmpeg to add a text watermark and define the position using a function,
`x=if(eq(mod(t\,4)\,0)\,rand(0\,500\)\,x)`, random position of x
I wanna to know why we have to use the trailing backslash?
Why can't we use `x=if(eq(mod(t,4),0),rand(0,500),x)`?

ERROR

```
...
[AVFilterGraph @ 0000029e7b56e7c0] No such filter: '100),x):y'
Error reinitializing filters!
...
```

**Here's the command**

`ffmpeg -i sample.mp4 -vf drawtext="text='Text Here':x=if(eq(mod(t\,4)\,0)\,rand(0\,100\)\,x):y=100" randomWatermark.mp4`.

I tried to remove any backSlash, but all failed.
even just remove backslash beside 0,as
`x=if(eq(mod(t\,4)\,0)\,rand(0,500\,x)`
I google a lot, the answers almost say it's a special character, [use to escaping characters](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-utils.html)  or used for another new line.

Comment: It's not a trailing backslash, it's a leading backslash. It's to escape commas as they delimit individual filters.

Comment: [Filter doc](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html)
Filters in the same linear chain are separated by commas, and distinct linear chains of filters are separated by semicolons. 
You saved my life, appreciate it. @Gyan